# Everyone at work

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

The cake is not just for Gina (a coworker of the speaker), **it's for everyone at work**, to apologize for my behavior the other day.

Question: Is it clear that "at work" refers to the speakers workplace? And is it natural in the context?

Comment: If you (speaker) are in your workplace already, you could simply use "here".

Comment: Yes, it is clear.

Comment: Even if you just said "it's for everybody" that is unlikely to be taken to mean "the whole world."